# convert index into columns - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[12,45,21,49],'c2':[67,86,28,55]})
```

I'd like to convert the index into columns

```
c1            c2
0  1  2  3    0  1  2  3 
12 45 21 49   67 86 28 55
```

I tried combining `stack` and `unstack` but so far without success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) + [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) + [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'c1':[12,45,21,49],'c2':[67,86,28,55]})
print (df.unstack().to_frame().T)
   c1              c2            
    0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3
0  12  45  21  49  67  86  28  55
```

Or [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) + [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) + [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, df.index])
print (pd.DataFrame(df.values.ravel().reshape(1, -1), columns=mux))
   c1              c2              c3            
    0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3   0   1   2   3
0  12  67  67  45  86  86  21  28  28  49  55  55
```